# Purpose of setRequestMethod and its parameters

Tags: java, android

void setRequestMethod (String method)
Set the method for the URL request, one of:

GET
POST
HEAD
OPTIONS
PUT
DELETE
TRACE

From my limited understanding, I believe that setRequestMethod("GET") just means that you are pulling the information from the data source/API. Is this correct? What do the other parameters do?

Comment: rfc 2616 - your answer starts [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.2).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Cheers!